Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Pairs of Observations
I have $n$ pairs of observations $(x_i,y_i)$, where each $y_i$ is distributed according to $\text{Pois}(\theta x_i)$, and I wish to do a maximum likelihood estimation for $\theta$ only based on this data. There is no known distribution for $x_i$, so I don't think I can do a conditional maximum likelihood since I don't have a marginal probability for $x_i$.
My approach was to find the log likelihood function $L(\theta x_i)$, then derive in terms of $\theta$ only so that I have an estimator for $\theta$ - for this my log likelihood function was
$$\sum[-\theta x_i + y_i\log(\theta x_i) - \log(y_i!)],$$
which gave me the estimator
$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{\sum y_i}{\sum x_i}.$$
Is this an appropriate approach?

The model you are proposing is a Poisson regression with the model form:
$$Y_i|\mathbf{x} \sim \text{Pois}(\mu_i)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\log \mu_i = \log \theta + \log x_i.$$
In this model the explanatory variables give an "offset" for the mean parameter.  The log-likelihood function for this model is:
$$\begin{align}
\ell_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(\theta)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \log \text{Pois}(y_i | \theta x_i) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n [ - \theta x_i + y_i \log(\theta x_i) - \log(y_i!) ] \\[6pt]
&= \text{const} - \theta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \log(\theta) \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \\[6pt]
&= \text{const} - n \Big[ \theta \bar{x}_n - \log(\theta) \bar{y}_n \Big]. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
The first and second derivatives of the log-likelihood are:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d \ell_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}}{d \theta}(\theta)
&= - n \Big[ \bar{x}_n - \frac{\bar{y}_n}{\theta} \Big], \\[14pt]
\frac{d^2 \ell_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}}{d \theta^2}(\theta)
&= - n \cdot \frac{\bar{y}_n}{\theta^2}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
This means that the log-likelihood is concave (strictly concave if $\bar{y}_n>0$ and non-strictly if $\bar{x}_n=0$), with MLE given by $\hat{\theta} = \bar{y}_n/\bar{x}_n$.
